# MySQL: How do you count non empty fields in a row, then count the same values?

Tags: mysql, select, count

Keep in mind that there's no way I can normalize the table, so I'm having to work with what I got. In the table, the rows are similar to this

```
name  |  widget1  |  widget2 | widget3 
------+-----------+----------+----------
Joe   |   blue    |   red    |          
Jane  |   green   |          |          
Bob   |   red     |   red    |  green
Susy  |   green   |  green   |
```

What I'd like to do is count the total number of widgets (Joe has 2 widget, Jane has 1, etc), and also count the number of similar widgets (Bob has 3 widgets - 2 red and 1 green, Susy has 2 widgets- 2 green, etc)

Here's my code to count the total number of widgets:

```
SELECT ( 
         SUM( IF(widget1 <> "", 1, 0) ) +
         SUM( IF(widget2 <> "", 1, 0) ) +
         SUM( IF(widget3 <> "", 1, 0) )
       ) AS totalWidgets FROM table
```

Which works fine. But is there a better way to do this?  Also, to count the number of similar of values, I'm sure I can so something similar but just check if the values are equal... but it could get pretty long and convoluted.

Is there a more direct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tested, but it should work

```
select name, count(1), SUM(widget = 'red') reds, SUM(widget = 'green') greens, SUM(widget = 'blue') blues
from
  (
    (SELECT name, widget1 widget FROM table)
   UNION
    (SELECT name, widget2 widget FROM table)
   UNION
    (SELECT name, widget3 widget FROM table)
  )q
WHERE widget <> ''
group by name;
```

All on one line

```
select name, count(1), SUM(widget = 'red') reds, SUM(widget = 'green') greens, SUM(widget = 'blue') blues from ((SELECT name, widget1 widget FROM table) UNION (SELECT name, widget2 widget FROM table) UNION (SELECT name, widget3 widget FROM table))q WHERE widget <> '' group by name;
```

`q` is our normalized "table" (not really a table, but it kinda looks like one).

See our normalized table this way

```
select * from ((SELECT name, widget1 widget FROM table) UNION (SELECT name, widget2 widget FROM table) UNION (SELECT name, widget3 widget FROM table))q;
```

Not sure what you call it, I think it is a subquery. (I have used MySQL for years and I **still** don't know the proper names)

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly. HeeHaw!